# event calls function with parameter - function executed with wrong parameter

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a map and a referring table. In the table are communities whose polygons are shown on the map. When I hover over an element in the table, the referring polygon on the map shall be highlighted. When the event *onmouseover* is fired, a function is called.

In the example below, I have a table row with the events *onmouseover* and *onmouseout*. On both events, the function "hoverMunicipality" shall be called, with the given id (0732130000000) and a truthy/falsy flag. The function is called, but the parameter I find in the debugger is 7941914624. Can somebody please untwist my brain?

```js
function hoverMunicipality(municipalityId, switchparam) {
  console.log(municipalityId, switchparam);
  if (switchparam == true) {
    let p = data.features.find(e=> e.properties.RS === municipalityId);
  }
  if (switchparam == false) {
    let p = data.features.find(e=> e.properties.RS === municipalityId);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr onmouseover="hoverMunicipality(073130000000, true)" 
      onmouseout="hoverMunicipality(073130000000, false)"><td>Gondor</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the values you are passing are not in quotes, they are treated as numbers. But, because those numbers begin with a zero, the system treats them as Octal (base 8) numbers and therefore you don't see the base 10 representation you were expecting.

You can just treat the numbers as strings and move forward with strings or you can start as strings and convert to numbers.

To use numbers, pss the numbers as strings and then parse the base 10 number out of those strings with `parseInt()`, being sure to pass the second optional argument (the radix) to specify a base 10 conversion. This will cause you to lose the leading zero in the initial value:

```js
function hoverMunicipality(municipalityId, switchparam) {
  // To convert the string to a base 10 number:
  console.log(parseInt(municipalityId,10));
  
  // Or just proceed with the data as a string:
  console.log(municipalityId);  

  // Other code here
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr onmouseover="hoverMunicipality('073130000000', true)" 
      onmouseout="hoverMunicipality('073130000000', false)"><td>Gondor</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Of course it is! Thanks, I was hanging on this one for too long.

Answer (score 2):

That number is octal representation. Pass that number as string and it should work the way you want.

Answer (score -1):

add apostrophe: '073130000000'

```html
<tr onmouseover="hoverMunicipality('07313000000', true)" onmouseout="hoverMunicipality('073130000000', false)"<td>Gondor</td></tr>
```

Comment: Simply saying what to change the code to and not explaining why is a poor answer.